# Can I create a flow to migrate state to new version instead of using contract upgrade?

Tags: corda

When I upgrade contract there are 2 step Authorise and Initiate. And since both step need to be done one by one per state (as my understanding) it take very long time when I have a large amount of data.

I ended up with looping call API to query some amount of data and then looping call ContractUpgradeFlow one by one.

The result is it took more than 11 hours and not finish upgrading.

So the question is if I create a flow A to query list of `StateV1` as an input and create an out output to be list of `StateV2`.

- Would it reduce the process for contract upgrade?
- Should it be faster?
- Is this considering same result like upgrade contract?
- Would it be any effect to the next contract upgrade for `StateV2` if I want to use Corda contract upgrade instead of flow A?

Answer (score 1):

Yes correct with an explicit upgrade if there is a lot of data, it is going to take time as lot of things are happening behind the scenes.

Each and every unconsumed state is taken, new transaction is created, old state with old contract and new states with new contract are 
added to this transaction, the transaction is sent to each signer for signing, setting of appropriate constraints is done, and finally the entire signed transaction is sent to notary.

“So the question is if I create a flow A to query list of StateV1 as an input and create an out output to be list of StateV2”

Yes you can very well create a flow to query list of StateV1 as an input and create an out output to be list of StateV2, but keep in mind you will also have to take care of all the steps which I have mentioned above which are as of now handled by the ContractUpgradeFlow.

“Would it reduce the process for contract upgrade?”

No I don’t think so as you will have to handle all the steps as mentioned above which are as of now handled by the ContractUpgradeFlow.

“Should it be faster?”

No it will take same time as taken by ContractUpgradeFlow